# Is diameter of a set a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Suppose the diameter of a nonempty set $A$ is defined as

$$\sigma(A) := \sup_{x,y \in A} d(x,y)$$

where $d(x,y)$ is a metric.

Is $\sigma(.)$ a 'measurement'? I.e., how do I prove the countable additivity for this particular case?

Comment: I was pretty much taught that diameter was the classic example of failure of measure.  $\sigma( [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q) + \sigma([0,1] \cap \mathbb R - \mathbb Q) = 1 + 1 \ne \sigma(([0,1]\cap \mathbb Q) \cup ([0,1]\cap \mathbb R - \mathbb Q) = \sigma ([0,1]) = 1$.

Comment: That is a very nice counter example. Thank you.

Comment: @fleablood How about 'measuring' $A\cup B$ just for $A=B=[0,1]$ or $A=\{1,3\}, B=\{2,3\}$...?

Comment: @CiaPan all very good.  A "distance" is pretty clear and basic measurement between points.  The need for "measure" is clearly because distance isn't at all good enough for "weight" or "thickness" or measuring just whats "in" the "inside" of the set.  All these examples show that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Observe that the diameter of singletons is $0$ and the diameter of set $\{x,y\}$ is $d(x,y)>0$ if $x\neq y$. So there is no additivity.

Comment: Same example ($A=\{ x\}, B=\{ y\}$) shows that $\sigma$ does not even satisfy the inequality $\sigma(A \cup B) \le \sigma(A) + \sigma(B)$ for disjoint $A$ and $B$ (finite subadditivity for disjoint sets).

Answer (score 17):

It's not even finitely additive. If $X$ and $Y$ are two disjoint closed intervals on the real line then the diameter of their union is not the sum of their diameters.

Answer (score 12):

... not to mention

$\sigma( \text{rational numbers between A and B}) + \sigma( \text {irrational numbers between A and B}) \ne \sigma( \text{ real numbers between A and B})$.

This is pretty much the perfect example of something that absolutely can not be a measure and illustrates why we need a concept of measure.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be a circle of diameter 1, and let $B$ a circle of diameter 2, having the same center of $A$. Note that $A \subseteq B$.

Now, $\sigma(B) = 2$, yet $\sigma(B \setminus A) + \sigma(A) = 2 + 1 = 3$.